# Send vertices from MainActivity to Renderer in OpenGL ES Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, renderer

I'm trying to write an Android application that uses OpenGL. 
What I want, is to send vertices from MainActivity to Renderer and then render this vertices on GLSurfaceView.
Is this possible? And how could I do this?

Comment: The specifics are different, but this question/answer shows one approach of how you can initiate a change in your rendering from the UI thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094705/glclearcolor-not-working-correct-android-opengl.

Answer (score 0):

Of course its possible. Start with a normal OpenGL application.
http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html
If you have never built something like that before you should at least go through the first four chapters. 
Once you have that running you can update the rendered objects from pretty much everywhere you like. At that point you should start thinking about the best datastructure. You dont want to draw vertices just by themselves right? You probably want to draw certain shapes? So you just manipulate a list of objects and your GLRenderer instance keeps drawing them.

Comment: It's not quite this simple. You can only make OpenGL calls from threads that have a current OpenGL context. So unless you create additional contexts, you can't directly construct/modify OpenGL objects from outside the rendering thread.

Comment: What is your specific problem? Maybe read part 6 of the tutorials from my link.

Comment: I built the application as your link. But it don't consider my problem. I want to send vertices from MainActivity instead define it in ShapeClass (e.g: Triangle)

Comment: Instead of calling "setAngle()" on the renderer you can supply any kind of datastructure e.g. a list of vertices. Use that list to update the buffers from which you are drawing. (Use flags to keep track of GL calls that need to be done in "onDraw()". Uploading vertex data to the GPU if needed.) You still have not explained in which way you want to render your vertices. Points, Lines, Triangles ...? A vertex is a coordinate and does not really have a visual shape.