# How to update bitmap in android opengl es 2.0 what have been binded textuer?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have been request texture id and It has been display ,but now i want to update what have been display ,for example
`private void initTexture(){
        int textureIds[] = new int[1];
        // 启用纹理
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureIds, 0);
        // 将绑定纹理(texuture[0]表示指针指向纹理数据的初始位置)
        mTextureID = textureIds[0];
    }`

```
public void freshTexture(){
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,mLayerDrawable.getBitmap(),0);
    onFreshView();

}
protected void doDraw() {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLES20.glClearColor(163,156,158,255);
    mGL20Factory.useProgram();
    MatrixState.setInitStack();
    MatrixState.transtate(mScreenPosition.getMoveX(mMoveX),mScreenPosition.getMoveY(mMoveY),0);
    MatrixState.scale(mScale,mScale,0);
    //将最终变换矩阵传入shader程序
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, MatrixState.getFinalMatrixMM(), 0);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mAttribPosition, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mVerticeBuf);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mAttribTexCoord, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mTextureCoodBuf);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mAttribPosition);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mAttribTexCoord);

    //绑定纹理
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mAttribPosition);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mAttribTexCoord);
}
```

other way,I use GLUtils.texSubImage2D() method ,but its not used,

Comment: Where are you calling `freshTexture()` from? Make sure that the code is executed in the rendering thread. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094705/glclearcolor-not-working-correct-android-opengl.

Comment: Thank you very much.Its useful.