# Android OpenGL save black image

Tags: android, bitmap, opengl-es, screenshot

When I wrote code like this..

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    /* codes */
    saveBitmap(takeScreenshot(gl));
}
```

It working perfect (take screenshot and save bitmap to sd card)

When I want use Button as a trigger

```
    Button btn;
        @Override
        public void onCreate{
           btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    saveBitmap(takeScreenshot(currGL10));
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            /* codes */
            currGL10 = gl;
        }
```

it saving the only black image.. I can't understand that what I lost with use like this.. Thank you

Comment: Work-around: Capture the `Bitmap` in onDrawFrame` and save it when the Button is clicked.

Comment: I've tried this, it is working.. I can't capture bitmap each time because my program use onDrawFrame() many times and it cause slowdown on performance..(takeScreenshot have nested for loop).. Thank you

Comment: Chances are that `saveBitmap()` makes a `glReadPixels()` call, which needs a current OpenGL context. So you can't call it from a thread other than the rendering thread. See for example here for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094705/glclearcolor-not-working-correct-android-opengl. It's not the same use case, but the same basic problem.

Comment: Thank you so much.. My foreign language isn't well so i can't understood completely that your wrote in other discuss but this gave me idea

Answer (score 2):

```
use this code its work fine .
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) {

        imageBitmap = takeScreenshot(arg0);

    }

**take a screenshot of open GlSurfaceView**

public Bitmap takeScreenshot(GL10 mGL) {

        final int mWidth = b_width;
        final int mHeight = b_height;

        IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight);
        IntBuffer ibt = IntBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight);
        mGL.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);

        // Convert upside down mirror-reversed image to right-side up normal
        // image.
        for (int i = 0; i < mHeight; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mWidth; j++) {
                ibt.put((mHeight - i - 1) * mWidth + j, ib.get(i * mWidth + j));
            }
        }

        Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255));
        mBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ibt);
        return mBitmap;
    }
```